# Crawling using Crawl spider class in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to recursively crawl URL's on a webpage and then parse these pages to get all the tags on the page. I tried crawling a single page using scrapy without recursively going into URL's on the page and it worked, but when I tried to change my code to make it crawl the entire site it crawls the site but gives a really weird error at the end. The code for the spider and the error is given below, the code takes the list of domains to crawl as an argument in a file.

```
import scrapy
from tags.items import TagsItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class TagSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "getTags"
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_tags', follow=True),)

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        for line in open(filename, 'r').readlines():
            self.allowed_domains.append(line)
            self.start_urls.append('http://%s' % line)

    def parse_start_url(self,response):
        return self.parse_tags(response)

    def parse_tags(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*').re(r'</?\w+\s+[^>]*>'):
            item = TagsItem()
            item['tag'] = sel
            item['url'] = response.url
            print item
```

This is the error dump I am getting:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest just copying the error message and including it in your question instead of linking to a screenshot.

Comment: Which scrapy version are you using? Also, you are not extracting any links - I doubt you need to set `rules` at all.